# How can I only store the second part of a string in a list?

Tags: c#

I have a list Textlist1 that contains only strings. Each item in the list begins with the same text: "sentence.text.", but I only want to store the second part of the string in another list, I don't want to store the first part "sentence.text." in the list Textlist2.

For example:

```
List<string> Textlist1 = new List<string>();
List<string> Textlist2 = new List<string>();
```

The full strings are stored in Textlist1.

```
Textlist1[0] = "sentence.text.My name is Fred"
Textlist1[1] = "sentence.text.Jenny is my sister"
```

How can I only add "My name is Fred" and "Jenny is my sister" to Textlist2?

The result should be like this:

```
Textlist2[0] = "My name is Fred"
Textlist2[1] = "Jenny is my sister"
```

Comment: All answers are perfectly valid. Hence +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See online result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MpswLZ

[image]

```
List<string> Textlist1 = new List<string>() {
   "sentence.text.My name is Fred", 
   "sentence.text.Jenny is my sister"
};

List<string> Textlist2 = new List<string>();

Textlist2 = Textlist1.Select(item => item.Split('.')[2]).ToList();
```

Comment: I must have posted whilst you were updating :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq. (You need do add `using System.Linq`)

```
Textlist2= Textlist1
    .Select(i=> i.Substring("sentence.text.".Length))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_System_TimeSpan_) the text.

```
var regex = new Regex("^sentence.text.",RegexOptions.Compiled);
Textlist2.AddRange(Textlist1.Select(x=>regex.Replace(x,string.Empty)));
```

The `"^"` in Regex ensure the required text (`"sentence.text"`) is matched only at the beginning of string and not else where.

**Sample Input**

[image]

**Sample Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Split the input strings by the periods, limiting the split to 3.  Then take the last entry from the array that split produces.

```
Textlist2[0] = Textlist1[0].Split('.', 3)[2];
Textlist2[1] = Textlist1[1].Split('.', 3)[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> Textlist1 = new List<string>
{
  "sentence.text.a",
  "sentence.text.b"
};
string prefix = "sentence.text.";
List<string> Textlist2 = Textlist1.Select(x => x.Substring(prefix.Length)).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/oFhvfs

There are ultimately many ways of doing this, this is just one solution. Which approach you choose depends on how complex the pattern replacement is. I've gone with a simplistic approach as your example is a very simple case.